# Richfaces not rendering properly

Tags: jsf, richfaces, render

I am new to richfaces and I am experiencing some problems in implementing it.

I am trying to implement a rich:tabPanel. It however will not be rendered. The text for the headers, and the content of the first tab are being shown as plain text.  I tried inserting another rich:calendar in the page and this is rendered correctly.
I am using rich 4.2.3

Here is the output for the tabPanel

```
Profile Enquiry LdapMgmt AccessMgmt 
«
↓
»
Profile Content
```

Here is a scaled-down version of my page

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:form>
    <rich:panel>
        <rich:tabPanel switchType="ajax" headerAlignment="left"
            style="background-color:#B5CEFD;width:100%">
            <rich:tab label="Profile" name="Profile">Profile Content</rich:tab>
            <rich:tab label="Enquiry" name="Enquiry">
Enquiry Content
            </rich:tab>
            <rich:tab label="LdapMgmt" name="LdapMgmt">Ldap User Management</rich:tab>
            <rich:tab label="AccessMgmt" name="AccessMgmt">Account Access Management</rich:tab>
        </rich:tabPanel>
    </rich:panel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a custom CSS for the faces components. This happened since I wasn't using the default style so the components had no style associated to them. Creating a custom style sheet for the components resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this for reference. The same can happen if you use ajax to render the tab and the tab css files weren't loaded. The solution is to make sure the tab CSS's are loaded on page load even if the tab is not to be shown.